# Save pandas groups to separate CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

Is it possible to return multiple `df`'s to independent `csv's` without using `.to_csv`. Using the code below I'm manually returning desired values and exporting those to a csv. This is ok if I only have a few files to export but if there's numerous files or file names that constantly change over datasets it can be cumbersome.

Is there a more efficient way to return desired values if you have a specific value list and export those to a csv?

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'C' : ['08:00:00','XX','08:10:00','XX','08:41:42','XX','08:50:00','XX', '09:00:00', 'XX','09:15:00','XX','09:21:00','XX','09:30:00','XX','09:40:00','XX'],
    'D' : ['Home','Home','Home','Home','Away','Away','Shops','Shops','Away','Away','Shops','Shops','Home','Home','Away','Away','Home','Home'],
    'E' : ['Num:','','Num:','','Num:','','Num:','','Num:', '','Num:','','Num:','','Num:', '','Num:', ''],
    'F' : ['1','','1','','1','','1','','1', '','2','','2','','1', '','2',''],   
    'A' : ['A','','A','','A','','A','','A','','A','','A','','A','','A',''],           
    'B' : ['Stop','','Res','','Stop','','Start','','Res','','Stop','','Res','','Start','','Start','']
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#List of designated places
values = ['Home', 'Away', 'Shops']

#Export to csv
Home = df.loc[df['D'] == 'Home'].to_csv('Home.csv')
Away = df.loc[df['D'] == 'Away'].to_csv('Away.csv')
Shops = df.loc[df['D'] == 'Shops'].to_csv('Shops.csv')
```

Comment: Sorry, fixed the duplicate link. You may want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871314/split-dataframe-into-a-dictionary-of-groups-from-multiple-columns/45871429#45871429

Comment: okay no, it's not enough. 1 second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter with `isin`, then perform a `groupby` on "D" and iteratively save to CSV.

```
incl = ['Home', 'Away', 'Shops']    
for k, g in df[df['D'].isin(incl)].groupby('D'):
    g.to_csv(f'{k}.csv')  # '{}.csv'.format(k)
```

The `isin` filtering step is important if and only if you have more categories than what you want to save. If this isn't the case and you want to save everything, your solution will simplify:

```
for k, g in df.groupby('D'):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed

Comment: This will probably have to be another question but could I add new columns before exporting?

Comment: @PeterJames123 it depends on what the columns are you want to add. Anything you need to do can be done inside the for loop.

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed. I got it half working https://stackoverflow.com/q/50831061/9394674