# Add new columns to a pandas df after filtering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, unique

I have a df that contains information about various places.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'C' : ['08:00:00','XX','08:10:00','XX','08:41:42','XX','08:50:00','XX', '09:00:00', 'XX','09:15:00','XX','09:21:00','XX','09:30:00','XX','09:40:00','XX'],
    'D' : ['Home','','Home','','Away','','Home','','Away','','Home','','Home','','Away','','Home',''],
    'E' : ['Num:','','Num:','','Num:','','Num:','','Num:', '','Num:','','Num:','','Num:', '','Num:', ''],
    'F' : ['1','','1','','1','','1','','1', '','2','','2','','1', '','2',''],   
    'A' : ['A','','A','','A','','A','','A','','A','','A','','A','','A',''],           
    'B' : ['Stop','','Res','','Stop','','Start','','Res','','Stop','','Res','','Start','','Start','']
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to export that data into their respective places, which are labelled in `Column D`. I also want to add new columns based off functions labelled in `Column B`.

```
df['C'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['C'], errors="coerce").dt.total_seconds()

incl = ['Home', 'Away']    

for k, g in df[df.D.isin(incl)].groupby('D'):
    Stop = g.loc[df['B'] == 'Stop'].reset_index()['C']
    Start = g.loc[df['B'] == 'Start'].reset_index()['C']
    Res = g.loc[df['B'] == 'Res'].reset_index()['C']

    g['Start_diff'] = Start - Stop
    g['Res_diff'] = Start - Res
```

The problem is these functions occur multiple times, which are labelled in `Column F`. So if we look at the export for `Home` we get the diff for the first time in `Column F`.

Output:

```
    A   B       C       D       E       F   Start_diff  Res_diff
0   A   Stop    28800   Home    Num:    1   3000        2400
2   A   Res     29400   Home    Num:    1       
6   A   Start   31800   Home    Num:    1       
10  A   Stop    33300   Home    Num:    2       
12  A   Res     33660   Home    Num:    2       
16  A   Start   34800   Home    Num:    2
```

Whereas I'm hoping the intended output would be:

```
    A   B       C       D       E       F   Start_diff  Res_diff
0   A   Stop    28800   Home    Num:    1   3000        2400
2   A   Res     29400   Home    Num:    1       
6   A   Start   31800   Home    Num:    1       
10  A   Stop    33300   Home    Num:    2   1500        1200    
12  A   Res     33660   Home    Num:    2       
16  A   Start   34800   Home    Num:    2
```

I have tried to alter `for k, g in df[df.D.isin(incl)].groupby('D'):` to `for k, g in df[df.D.isin(incl)].groupby('D').F.nunique():`

But I get an error `TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe need custom function with groupby by `D` and `F` columns with replace duplicated values by `mask`:

```
def f(g):
    Stop = g.loc[df['B'] == 'Stop', 'C']
    Start = g.loc[df['B'] == 'Start', 'C']
    Res = g.loc[df['B'] == 'Res', 'C']
    g['Start_diff'] = Start.values[0] - Stop.values[0]
    g['Res_diff'] = Start.values[0] - Res.values[0]

    return (g)

df = df[df.D.isin(incl)].groupby(['D', 'F']).apply(f)

df[['Start_diff', 'Res_diff']] = df[['Start_diff', 'Res_diff']].mask(df.duplicated(['D','F']))
print (df)
          C     D     E  F  A      B  Start_diff  Res_diff
0   28800.0  Home  Num:  1  A   Stop      3000.0    2400.0
2   29400.0  Home  Num:  1  A    Res         NaN       NaN
4   31302.0  Away  Num:  1  A   Stop      2898.0    1800.0
6   31800.0  Home  Num:  1  A  Start         NaN       NaN
8   32400.0  Away  Num:  1  A    Res         NaN       NaN
10  33300.0  Home  Num:  2  A   Stop      1500.0    1140.0
12  33660.0  Home  Num:  2  A    Res         NaN       NaN
14  34200.0  Away  Num:  1  A  Start         NaN       NaN
16  34800.0  Home  Num:  2  A  Start         NaN       NaN
```